# How to keep only one row of a table when deleting all rows?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I don't know how to use this query.

I want delete all record but keep only one.

I tried using `NOT IN` but I don't know how:

```
DELETE FROM members
WHERE ID NOT IN
```

Comment: add your query and code snippet.

Comment: No sir there not any duplicates records. If I Setect keep No.5 records then keep only one no.5 records and delete remaning all

Comment: And which record do you want to keep?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
DELETE FROM members WHERE ID NOT IN (id_you_dont_want_to_delete);
```

This will workout

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM members WHERE id <> 42;
```

Answer (score 0):

you want to delete Duplicates you can use Co related Query 
like bellow

```
DELETE FROM our_table
WHERE rowid not in
(SELECT MIN(rowid)
FROM our_table
GROUP BY column1, column2, column3) ;
```

if you want to delete other then one record you can use like bellow

```
 DELETE FROM members WHERE id <> 1;
```